# Total Objects based on Value of Another Object

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django 1.8.3 and Python 3.4.3

I will try and explain this the best I can.  If there's a better title for this post, please suggest.

We pull data into our app from email and website traffic sources and then display the data in a table format in the views template.  I am adding a table to display totals which will help us visualize our email campaigns better.  One thing I would like to render is the total campaign months the current data represents.  For example:  If we are tracking data from January to June, our total campaign months would be 6.

I am new to Python so its been difficult to pull together a solution, especially since I need to count a string array (months) and provide and int return (6 - with the above example).

Below is my model class, models.py

```
class Email(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    month = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    day_of_week = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subject_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_list = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    recipients = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    unsubscribes = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    bounces = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    open = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

So, what I am trying to accomplish is if looking at the above models - what is the `month` count if the sum of the `recipients` is not equal to 0, so for every month the recipient is not equal to 0, that month would add 1 to the month count.

Here is a snippet of my views.py file to show how we get the current count for the recipients on a monthly basis.

views.py

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmailListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
        months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October',
                  'November', 'December']
        subject_type = ['Offer', 'Sell', 'Fear', 'Learn']
        content_type = ['Offer', 'Sell', 'Fear', 'Learn']
        email_list = ['FMGB', 'FMGR', 'AE', 'IBA']

        total_campaigns = {}
        total_recipients = {}
        total_unsubscribes = {}
        total_bounces = {}
        total_open = {}
        total_clicks = {}
        total_campaigns_content = {}
        total_recipients_content = {}
        total_unsubscribes_content = {}
        total_bounces_content = {}
        total_open_content = {}
        total_clicks_content = {}
        total_campaigns_subject = {}
        total_recipients_subject = {}
        total_unsubscribes_subject = {}
        total_bounces_subject = {}
        total_open_subject = {}
        total_clicks_subject = {}

for month in months:
            # total count
            total_campaigns[month] = Email.objects.filter(month=month).count()
            # recipients
            total_recipients[month] = Email.objects.filter(month=month).aggregate(
                Sum('recipients')).get('recipients__sum', 0.00)
            # unsubscribes
            total_unsubscribes[month] = Email.objects.filter(month=month).aggregate(
                Sum('unsubscribes')).get('unsubscribes__sum', 0.00)
            # bounces
            total_bounces[month] = Email.objects.filter(month=month).aggregate(Sum('bounces')).get(
                'bounces__sum', 0.00)
            # opens
            total_open[month] = Email.objects.filter(month=month).aggregate(
                Sum('open')).get('open__sum', 0.00)
            # clicks
            total_clicks[month] = Email.objects.filter(month=month).aggregate(
                Sum('clicks')).get('clicks__sum', 0.00)
             ...
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should get the job done:

```
count = Email.objects.filter(recipients__gt=0).values('month').distinct().count()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you intend to do and how your model works, you can do something like this:

```
count = 0
for month in months:
    temp = Email.objects.filter(month=month, recipients != 0)
    if temp:
        count = count + 1
```

temp is None if no objects match the filter, so `if temp` only runs if there is an email with at least 1 recipient, and I'm guessing you can't have negative recipients, so if one email has recipients > 0 then the sum for recipients in that month is not zero.